# How to make own shaped control c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

IDE: Visual Studio 2010, C# .net 4.0, Windows Form application.

As we can divide a windows form using panel. Now in my project the requirement is to divide the panel in angular shaped.

[image]

In this image i have created sections using panels (in square shape). But the problem is this is 3D image so we can't divide road and grass using panels symmetrically.
So i want to make my own panel in angular shape as u can see white section in same image.

for this i have studied this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289517%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
 but i don't think this is helpful for this problem because i want to make my own shaped panel.

so please suggest how can i make this type of panel or control so i can divide this image symmetrically.

Comment: I strongly recommend WPF for this instead of winforms.

Comment: I am new for WPF, can u suggest to speedy getting start and make this work done.

Comment: *why* do you think you want a child control on this form?  Do you simply want to interact with it through mouse events?  You say there is a one 3D image that you can divide, so it sounds like you just want mouse interaction of a region of the window?

Comment: yes u r right, I want to divide this image in sections using angular panels ( because default panel is not useful to divide this) to generate different event in different sections.

Comment: I would then simply make a decision on what to do with a mouse event based on position.  This could be done with an image map and the colour of the pixel at a point could be used as the delineator.  For example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163585.aspx

Comment: You'll have to create a Region from, say, GraphicsPath.AddPolygon() and assign it to the control's Region property.  Doing this with controls is not a very good idea.  Once you calculated the polygons, hit-testing becomes trivial as well of course.