# How to create a parallogram user control?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

Before reading this please see my other post:

[How to make own shaped control c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559036/how-to-make-own-shaped-control-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment32562758_21559036)

After some research I found a solution that I can divide this image using parallelogram. I have found other controls such as diamond here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10558/Shape-Control-for-NET

My problem can be solved if there is a way to rotate the diamond shape in some angle so I can use it as parallelogram but i have not found any way.

Its dll is not providing parallelogram shape control. Please suggest how to create my own shape so i can use it. or if you know any  dll please suggest.

Comment: How is this question different from your previous one?

Comment: The previous question is not answered and here i have mentioned that I can use parallelogram. Why u asking this?

Comment: I'm asking this because it's unclear what you're asking. You link to some code someone else wrote, which has no documentation, and ask _"Can I rotate the diamond shape, or please suggest me another library"_. I took a look at the code, and it uses the `GraphicsPath` class to render the shapes. If you search the web for "GraphicsPath rotate", you'll find the [`GraphicsPath.Transform()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.transform(v=vs.110).aspx) method. So my question is: did you find that, did you try anything?

Comment: No, I have not found any perfect solution. my target is to divide the road with parallelogram shape instead of panel because panel is similar to rectangle so it is not useful. so i want a control which can divide this image in symmetric way.

Comment: Don't ignore the comments made in your duplicate question.  You seem dead set on having a control, but what you really want is just a class that holds your shape information and then just draw on the form's image.